# How can I create the characteristic warp core sound?

Tags: 555, sound

I'm trying to build a miniature warp core (purely decorative, not functional) with the main element being an LED chaser circuit with 10 LEDs. I'm planning on using a 555 timer and a 4017 decade counter like described in many examples one can find on the internet for LED chaser circuits ([example](http://www.circuitdiagram.org/led-sequencer-chaser-ne555-4017.html)).

Now I had the idea that the miniature warp core would be much more impressive if it actually produced [the typical warp core sound](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZcFWEN1Pzc) while it is active, synchronized to the chasing LEDs.

The sound would not have to be the exact sound of course, any oscillating low humming that could conceivable be caused by the engine of a starship would do. Unfortunately my experience with building electronic circuits is extremely limited, so I'm not sure how to produce such a sound. In my naive understanding it could work e.g. by creating a low base sound using another 555 and then somehow use the signal from the 555 driving the LEDs to modify the base sound.

Comment: So you are interested in a low-pitched, repeated thrumming noise that would sync to the lights?

Comment: @mikeY Something like that. It should sound like something out of a science fiction engine room.

Comment: It would seem to me that there might be two basic approaches.  The first would be to create original tones through circuitry and the second to trigger/play/invoke a prepared/recorded sound.

Comment: Personally, when I have done projects like this, I have used a microcontroller and something like the [Wave Shield](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-wave-shield-audio-shield-for-arduino) for Arduino to store sound files on SD card and play them back through a DAC and amplifier. It's not as involved (for better or worse) but it is definitely quick.

Comment: +1 for clarifying that the miniature warp core would be purely decorative.

Comment: -1 for clarifying that the miniature warp core would be purely decorative.  <just kidding>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll never do it with a 555.

Start by ripping a DVD of the TV show or movie.  Isolate the warp core sound.  Create an MP3 of that sound (and any others that you might be interested in).  Then buy one of [these things](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11029), put it all together.  And you're done.